# How to define PropTypes for Array<Object|string>

Tags: arrays, reactjs, string, react-proptypes

I have a prop named `options` which is an array with object or string. How can we use React PropTypes to define `options`? I just went through https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html

From PropTypes doc:

```
     // An array of a certain type
      optionalArrayOf: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.number),
```

but how we can put string and object into `PropTypes.arrayOf` ? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To specify the propType for the `options` array that can have strings and objects, both at the same time,
declare its PropType like this:

```
options: PropTypes.arrayOf(
    PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.string, PropTypes.object])
  )
```

This will accept an all strings array, an all objects array or an array with strings and objects both.

Comment: @yang-wang, if this helped answer your question, please accept this answer and upvote it.